# Getting information from OrientationEventListener manually on Android

Tags: android, orientation, listener

I am using `OrientationEventListener` to get information from orientation sensor. I am `@Overriding` the `onOrientationChanged(int orientation)` method and everything is working great.

There is only one small problem, if the app is launched and the orientation does not change since it start I never get `onOrientationChanged` method to start and never get idea about the orientation of the phone.

Is there a way to somehow send information to `OrientationEventLister` that the orientation has "changed" manually? Thus running through the `onOrientationChanged` method and get the initial orientation at the beginning.

Answer (score -1):

You can access current orientation via [Configuration](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Configuration.html) class. And you can access current configuration via [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) instance.

Comment: Configuration Class does not report orientation in degrees. See what's `onOrientationChanged` really into [here].(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/OrientationEventListener.html#onOrientationChanged(int))